# In AWS cloudformation, what is the difference between a custom resource and a resource provider?

Tags: aws-cloudformation

As per my understanding:

- A custom resource is just an AWS Lambda function that runs whenever the stack is provisioned or updated or deleted.
- A resource provider is plain old code where one writes hooks for all the Stack operations (update, create, delete, etc).

I can't see why anyone would use the former over the latter. Resource providers seem easier to write and test.

Comment: https://twitter.com/__steele/status/1219102291350786048

Comment: https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/mt/managing-resources-using-aws-cloudformation-resource-types/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One historical reason is that custom resources were the only option until recently:

[CloudFormation Release History](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/ReleaseHistory.html)

[18 Nov 2019 Resource Provider announcement](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/cloudformation-update-cli-third-party-resource-support-registry/)